# Questions with short titles

Tags: discussion

These questions have less than 18 characters in their titles, perhaps some of them need more descriptive title:

[Ash tree gender](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/34370)

[Lawn renovation](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/23771)

[Leaves seem burnt](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/8112)

[Sowing Tiny Seeds](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/34703)

[Sizing a hothouse](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/30085)

[Is this root rot?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/35224)

[Raspberry disease](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/9049)

[Spots on lemons](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/35591)

[My new jade plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/4511)

[Is my aloe dead?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/20300)

[Droopy peace lily](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/31158)

[Palm tree disease](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/31226)

[Spearmint Yield](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/20468)

[How to sell seeds](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/4738)

[Is this a cactus?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/21887)

[Pruning a mimosa](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/5447)

[Revive aloe plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/33206)

[Sequoia Browning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/5692)

[Is it a ladybird?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/22505)

[Excavating a yard](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/27333)

[Tall Living Fence](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/5920)

[Tree root damage](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/27378)

[Hexagonal bush?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/7285)

[Too Many Spiders](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/28788)

[Potatoes chewed](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/34058)

[Do I have moles?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/34136)

Comment: Hi VividD! I left a comment on the duplicate question too, since they're linked. I'm glad you addressed this. Both of your concerns are important. I love to edit and will try to help with some of the editing. I just want to suggest that we don't edit too many questions at the same time. What happens is it brings them forward to the "active" questions list, and can take attention away from the newer questions. Other than that, go to it!!

Comment: @Sue Good! Go ahead!

Comment: When editing a long title, I found a dead link and some small mistakes in the answer. I'm not saying you have time to check every answer, but if anything glaring stands out, an edit to those would be helpful too.

Comment: I deleted your reference to the [Spearmint yield](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/20468/spearmint-yield). It's closed, unanswered, and the OP hasn't been back since he posted it in August of 2015, so I didn't want to bring it forward. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: By the way, even if the questions on your list have been edited, you should always feel free to re-edit if you'd like it to be different!

Comment: @Sue The list is obtained mechanically, using some methods for accessing database, so it could be that some are closed etc. Or unsuitable for editing in any other way... Those are just candidates.

Comment: @Sue I am a kind of tired of editing, I am going to make some break for certain time I guess.... :)

Comment: I don't blame you. It's a big project and there's plenty of time to do it!  Other people who see this will probably also help.

Answer (score 7):

You have full [edit privileges](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). From that page:

> #### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!

If you think a title can be improved, please do so, and remember to also fix all the problems in the post (spelling, grammar, punctuation, etc.) while you're at it.

Answer (score 3):

What it wrong to have short or long titles?  I think most of the cases, the size is acceptable.

On your list of short question, I would just add the question ("What", "How", "Why"), to make clear that it is a question. But sometime the question is really short.

I think we should also check the answers. If the answer is generic, it is good to have a generic question. Instead if the answers are not generic, the title should be corrected. This is often the case when it is not possible to answer generically, so we ask in comments about details (and questioner answer also in comment, instead of changing title or question details).

On the other hand, I tend not to like the very long title. I cannot quickly parse the question list, to see check the topic I'm interested in (either to read answers, or to write an answer).

IMHO, a description of the picture should be put into the question details (just to help search engines, so user with the same problem). The title could just have a very short description (e.g. region and the main characteristic).